# set_sale_price in WooCommerce

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, oop

I need to set a WooCommerce sales price in a function. I'm using set_sale_price - but I don't think it is working.

I'm trying it two different ways:
Method one:

```php
    update_post_meta( $theID, '_sale_price', $theFinalSalePrice );
```

and Method two:

```php
    $editedProduct = wc_get_product( $theID );
    $editedProduct->set_sale_price($theFinalSalePrice);
```

Method One does update the sales price - however, from what I understand, using this method prevents the product from "clearing the cache" and therefore it does not appear in the shortcode which should show on_sale products.

Method Two should be the correct method which will cause that product to appear in the shortcode output - however it fails to actually set the _sale_price.

So, if I use method one, and I create a manual loop that shows sale items, then the product will show up in the loop output, but not in the output of the products shortcode (with on_sale set to true). If I use method two, it shows up in neither, because the sale price was never set.

I can only assume that I am misunderstanding how to properly use the set_sale_price method. I'm hoping someone will recognize my error. Thanks for the help.

Edit: 
I have found two pieces of info that might help me solve this: 
In the wc_product_meta_lookup table, there is a value "onsale" which was set to 0 in a product which did have a sale price, but did not show up in the sale listings. That value was set to 1 in a different product which did have a sale price and did show up in the sale listings. So, I set it to 1 in the first product, to indicate, I assume, that it is "onsale."

This did not result in the product showing up in the sale listing. But - after more searching, I found that if I `delete_transient( ‘wc_products_onsale’ );` at the beginning of my function, that this newly edited product does show up in sale listings.

So, it seems like I can solve the problem by setting the onsale value for each newly onsale product to 1, and then `delete_transient( ‘wc_products_onsale’ );` to clear the transient of the onsale products.

My only last lost bit is that I don't know how to set that value.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a colleague at codeable I was able to solve this by saving the product after setting the sale price:

`$editedProduct->save();`

Simple as that. If only I'd known that 6 hours ago!